# Wondering why this while loop isn't stopping

Tags: python

```
end_number = -99
num = (input("Enter Nnumber: "))
list_of_numbers = []
list_of_numbers.append(num)
while num != end_number:
    num = (input("Enter Nnumber: "))
print("The smallest number was", min(list_of_numbers))
print("The smallest number was", max(list_of_numbers))
```

I am trying to a have a person enter a bunch of int and stop when they ender -99. Then I'm wanting to print the smallest and largest in they entered.

Comment: The list_of_numbers.append(num) should be within the while loop. Otherwise how will the list get updated with the current inputs.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code. These techniques can help you get closer to solving problems like this on your own.

Answer (score 7):

`input()` returns a string and `end_number` is int, either convert the result of `input()` to int, with

```
num = int(input("Enter Nnumber: "))
```

or convert `end_number` to string, with

```
end_number = "-99"  # Double quotes to represent -99 as a String of characters
```

Comment: Converting the inputs to int is necessary to get the expected output. Otherwise, as an example, `min(["1000", "99"])` returns "1000" due to string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
end_number = -99
list_of_numbers = []

while True:
    num = int(input("Enter Nnumber: "))

    if num == end_number:
        break
    else:
        list_of_numbers.append(num)

print("The smallest number was", min(list_of_numbers))
print("The smallest number was", max(list_of_numbers))
```

Some recaps:

- Consider using `while True`
- `list_of_numbers.append(num)` should be within while loop.
- Your input should be `int` and within while loop.
- You should checked whether `num` is equal to `end_number` within while
  loop.
- You need `break` to stop the loop if `num` equals `end_number`

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't stop because `num` is not an integer when compared to `end_number` which is `int` in the beginning. Then it keeps repeating for input because input in `while` is also a string.

The element in `list_of_numbers` is a string and it only contains 1 element because it gets appended just once. So you should move your `list_of_numbers.append(num)` within `while` loop and convert `num` to `int` to get min and max value later.

You might need `if` and `break` to stop the loop when `num` equals `end_numbers`, otherwise it always gets -99 as min value.

So it goes like this:

```
while num != end_number:
    num = int(input("Enter Nnumber: "))
    if num == end_number: break
    list_of_numbers.append(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is data types as input takes default type as string convert it to int to get value.
as "-99"!=-99

```
end_number = -99
num = int(input("Enter Number: "))
list_of_numbers = []
list_of_numbers.append(num)
while num != end_number:
    num = int(input("Enter Number: "))
    list_of_numbers.append(num)
print("The smallest number was", min(list_of_numbers))
print("The smallest number was", max(list_of_numbers))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
end_number = -99
num = (input("Enter Nnumber: "))
list_of_numbers = []
list_of_numbers.append(num)
while num != end_number:
    num = int(input("Enter Nnumber: "))
print("The smallest number was", min(list_of_numbers))
print("The smallest number was", max(list_of_numbers))
```

---

### *Data Types In Python*

In python, We have Data Types such as Integers, Strings, Floats and None Types.

- Integers are **whole** numbers such as 5, 1, -234, 100134
- Strings are words and sentences such as, "Hello, World!" or "Nice to meet you!"
- Floats are decimal numbers, like, 0.342112, 4.98, -12.23

These data types can not be interchanged without the use of certain functions,
For example.

"5" == 5 = False

5 == 5 = True

"5" == **str(5)** = True.

str() turns a data type into a string.

int() turns a data type into a integer

float() turns a data type into a decimal.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I am trying this

```
list_of_numbers = []
while (num := int(input("Enter Nnumber: "))) != -99: list_of_numbers.append(num)
print("The smallest number was", min(list_of_numbers))
print("The smallest number was", max(list_of_numbers))
```